# How to debug a "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable" error in Python?

Tags: matplotlib, graph, patch, index-error

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.patches as pat
oval = pat.Ellipse(v1_mean,v2_mean,v1_std*2,v2_std*2)

fig,graph = plt.subplots()
graph.scatter(v1,v2)
graph.scatter(v1_mean,v2_mean, s=100)
graph.text(v1_mean,v2_mean, 'Mean')
graph.add_patch(oval)
```

And this is the error that comes:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-2278a0e6f4cf> in <module>()
      7 graph.scatter(v1_mean,v2_mean, s=100)
      8 graph.text(v1_mean,v2_mean, 'Mean')
----> 9 graph.add_patch(oval)
     10 
     11 graph.xlabel('V1')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in add_patch(self, p)
   2033         if p.get_clip_path() is None:
   2034             p.set_clip_path(self.patch)
-> 2035         self._update_patch_limits(p)
   2036         self.patches.append(p)
   2037         p._remove_method = lambda h: self.patches.remove(h)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _update_patch_limits(self, patch)
   2053         vertices = patch.get_path().vertices
   2054         if vertices.size > 0:
-> 2055             xys = patch.get_patch_transform().transform(vertices)
   2056             if patch.get_data_transform() != self.transData:
   2057                 patch_to_data = (patch.get_data_transform() -

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py in get_patch_transform(self)
   1492 
   1493     def get_patch_transform(self):
-> 1494         self._recompute_transform()
   1495         return self._patch_transform
   1496 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py in _recompute_transform(self)
   1476                  not directly access the transformation member variable.
   1477         """
-> 1478         center = (self.convert_xunits(self.center[0]),
   1479                   self.convert_yunits(self.center[1]))
   1480         width = self.convert_xunits(self.width)

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is plot an oval shape and some data into the same graph. But it seems like the error has got to do with the center of the oval, but I dont know what is exactly wrong. It's strange that I followed exactly what the teacher has done, but mine came with an error while his is ok.

Answer (score 0):

> It's strange that I followed exactly what the teacher has done, but mine came with an error while his is ok.

Probably you didn't follow exactly. According to the documentation of [`matplotlib.patches.Ellipse`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.html) the *xy coordinates of ellipse centre* are to be given as a tuple rather than individual arguments, so it's not

```
oval = pat.Ellipse(v1_mean,v2_mean,v1_std*2,v2_std*2)
```

but

```
oval = pat.Ellipse((v1_mean, v2_mean), v1_std*2, v2_std*2)
```

instead. Unfortunately `Ellipse` didn't warn about this and stored a single number as the ellipse center.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much for your help! I am finally able to solve this thing that had been bugging me for weeks lol